# print a web page with inline css

Tags: printing-web-page, inline-styles

I want to print an html table with inline style for particular cells. This is the image of the table.

[image]

but when I print this web page out. the colors for those cells disappear. This is the image of the print preview.

[image]

This is the code sample of the table:

[image]

I know that I can set media type to print for css classes to print those colors out. But there are hundreds of colors available and creating a class for each of them will be a nightmare.

U guys got any solution to print this table with colored cells out?

Answer (score 1):

This was a while ago ... maybe this no longer an issue with today's browsers? 
They will print background colors if asked to do so. At least it worked for me, and I have pretty much exactly the same situation (inline css generated individually for each cell by PHP). 
See https://rewordify.com/BackgroundColors.htm